# Asp.Net CustomValidator is not generating equal functions in java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working on a registration page of my Asp.Net website. When we use Server side Asp.net built-in validation controls, they work both on client side (by generating appropriate java script code) and offer server side protection too. So if somebody circumvent that java script, still the page has to be validated on the server. Currently i am using my own asp.net C# functions in Custom Validators to do the job but these only works on server side. I mean the equal java script is not automatically generated on my web form. Is it the default behavior of Asp.Net or am i missing anything? Do I have to write my client side java script on myself when i use asp.net custom validators?

My 2nd question is when we write function for our asp.net custom validator. They are called when the page is submitted to server. can i access such function with java script, so that the will start working before the page is submitted to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a custom validator you have to write your own validation code in both javascript and C#

If you attach some javascript to the validator it will fire along with all the standard .net validators on the page, so errors can get caught before postback

You need to make sure the ClientValidationFunction method is set.

```
<asp:CustomValidator 
     id="ProgrammaticID" 
     ControlToValidate="programmatic ID of Server Control to Validate"
     ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidateID"
     OnServerValidate="ServerValidateID"
     ErrorMessage="Message to display in ValidationSummary control"
     Text="Message to display in control" 
     ForeColor="value" 
     BackColor="value"  
     runat="server" >
</asp:CustomValidator>
```